# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redsquare.moduloMatriculas'" DJANGO

Tags: python, django, import, architecture, python-import

I'm trying to import a models.py file from moduloMatriculas in moduloFormaturas, however the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redsquare.moduloMatriculas'" occurs
redsquare means the name of the project, in the image it has a red square.

Arquitetura

[image: Arquitetura]

Django import models

[image: Django import models]

Comment: If `moduloMatriculas` is in the project directory (the one containing `manage.py`) then you don't have to include the project name when you import it. Try `from moduloMatriculas.models import Aluno`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it really worked, but please, can you answer us why this "error" occurs? the import is underlined in red

Comment: When you run `manage.py`, the project directory `moduloMatriculas` is on the Python path therefore you shouldn't include it in the imports. The red underline is from your editor, so you need to configure it to set the Python path correctly (the instructions will be different for each editor, I can't help with that).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `pip` default package.

In `cmd`, get to the `python` location and then:

```
cd Scripts --> pip install [your package name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regieter the respective  app from.which you want to import  the models.py in INSTALLED APPS 
in settings.py file